# The limit of a function on open interval

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if a function $f:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is non-decreasing and bounded, then there is $\lim_{x \rightarrow b} f(x)$.

I'm gonna give a sketch of what I've came up with, as my final attempt at the time.

Let $t= \sup\{f(x), x \in (a,b), x<b\}$
Suppose $t = lim_{x \rightarrow b} f(x)$. As such, $\epsilon >0$, $t- \epsilon$ is not an upper bound of the set $\{f(x), x \in (a,b); x<b \}$.
So there is $\delta > 0$ such as $b- \epsilon \in (a,b)$ and $t- \epsilon \leqslant f(b- \delta) < t+ \epsilon$. And $f$ is non-decreasing, if $x\in (a,b)$ and $b- \delta \leqslant x < b + \delta$ then $ t- \epsilon < f(x) \leqslant t+ \epsilon $.

Comment: By "limited" do you mean "bounded"?

Comment: @João Fagundes I do not speak Portuguese, but by similarity to Spanish I guess you mean "bounded". The word "limited" may cause confusion when talking about limits.

Comment: Yes by limited, i mean bounded. I translated from portuguese, sorry.

Comment: Show $\sup f < \infty$ and then show that $\lim _{x \to b} f(x) = \sup f$.

Comment: The OP has shown what he tried or thought; why is there a "-1"? :)

Comment: @GudsonChou: A lot of nit-pickers on SE sites. At least people tend to be reasonably polite on MSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is bounded, the set 
$$A=\{f(x):x\in(a,b)\}$$
is non-empty and bounded. Let $L=\sup A$.

Now let $\epsilon >0$. Then $L-\epsilon$ is not an upper bound of $A$, that is, there exist some $\delta>0$ such that $f(b-\delta)>L-\epsilon$. For $x\in(b-\delta,b)$ we have $L\ge f(x)\ge f(b-\delta)>L-\epsilon$, that is, $L-f(x)=|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

Thus,
$$\lim_{x\to b^-} f(x)=L$$

Comment: i think that my last update has almost the same ideia, so i think i was right then. thank you. Can you check it, please?

Answer (score 1):

If $f: ]a,b[ \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded, then there is some $M \geq 0$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all $x \in ]a,b[$ by definition, so $s:= \sup f]a,b[$ exists by axiom; if $f$ is nondecreasing, then $f(x) \leq s$ for all $x \in ]a,b[$ by definition. Let $\varepsilon > 0$; then by definition there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $s - \varepsilon < f(b-\delta) \leq f(x) \leq s$ for all $b-\delta < x < b$,  but this is a rephrase of the definition of the left-handed limit.